# Same BarData shows different in BarChart and CombinedChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using **MPAndroidChart2.2.5** to draw charts in my project,which contains 2 group of `BarData`and 1 group of `LineData`.When I use the `BarData` in Barchart,the bars shows well.But when I use the same `BarData` in CombinedChart,the position of the bars differs.Here's my activity.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

```
public class CombinedChartActivity extends BaseActivity {

private CombinedChart combinedChart;
private BarChart barChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_combined_chart);

    combinedChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barChart);

    initChart(combinedChart);
    initChart(barChart);

    barChart.setData(getBarData());

    CombinedData combinedData = new CombinedData();
    combinedData.setXVals(getXVals());
    combinedData.setData(getLineData());
    combinedData.setData(getBarData());
    combinedChart.setData(combinedData);
}

private void initChart(BarLineChartBase barLineChartBase) {
    barLineChartBase.setDescription("");
    barLineChartBase.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    barLineChartBase.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    barLineChartBase.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    barLineChartBase.getXAxis().setGridColor(R.color.white);
    barLineChartBase.getXAxis().setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    barLineChartBase.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}


private BarData getBarData() {
    List<IBarDataSet> iBarDataSets = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry(i + 1, i);
        barEntries.add(barEntry);
    }
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Bar1");
    barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
    barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry((float) (i + Math.random() * 10), i);
        barEntries2.add(barEntry);
    }
    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries2, "Bar2");
    barDataSet1.setColor(R.color.level_3);
    barDataSet1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);

    iBarDataSets.add(barDataSet);
    iBarDataSets.add(barDataSet1);

    BarData barData = new BarData(getXVals(), iBarDataSets);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    return barData;
}

private LineData getLineData() {
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        Entry entry = new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 10), i);
        entries.add(entry);
    }
    List<ILineDataSet> iLineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    LineDataSet lds1 = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line");
    lds1.setLineWidth(0.2f);
    lds1.setColor(R.color.level_3);
    lds1.setDrawFilled(true);
    lds1.setFillAlpha(150);
    lds1.setFillColor(R.color.level_2);
    lds1.setDrawValues(false);
    lds1.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lds1.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
    lds1.setHighLightColor(R.color.white);
    lds1.setDrawCubic(true);

    lds1.setDrawCircles(true);
    lds1.setCircleColor(R.color.white);
    lds1.setCircleColorHole(R.color.theme_orange);
    lds1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    iLineDataSets.add(lds1);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(getXVals(), iLineDataSets);
    return lineData;

}

private List<String> getXVals() {
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
    xVals.add("Monday");
    xVals.add("Tuesday");
    xVals.add("Wednesday");
    xVals.add("Thursday");
    xVals.add("Friday");
    xVals.add("Saturday");
    xVals.add("Sunday");
    return xVals;
}
}
```

I use same **BarData** in both charts.What causes the difference.How can I make the bars in **Combinedchart** show as in the **Barchart**?